# Mobile Text Selection Context Menus (with PhoneGap or otherwise)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I'm building a web application for use with mobile devices using PhoneGap. iOS and Android show context menus with options to copy/paste, search, share, etc. when text is selected. I'd like to add an item to these menus (e.g. "add a note here"). Is there a way to do this with JS or PhoneGap?

Comment: Same question here. You ever figure this one out?

Comment: @JayGee I never found a way. As a work around I added a bottom toolbar to the UI so I could present tools without interfering with the native OS context menus. (If you're having trouble with detecting selection, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) should get you started.)